# Calculate the quadratic residues in Z∗17.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratics

Hello I am wondering if any one can help me I am trying to figure out how these below answers where came to too.

Calculate the quadratic residues in Z∗17.

Solution:
This can be done by direct calculation. Since the quadratic residues are symmetric, they only need to be calculated for half of the values.

In this case the quadratic residues are: 1, 4, 9, 16,8, 2, 15, 13.

I would grateful if someone could step me though this step by step. As cant seem to get this.

Comment: Compute $1^2$. Compute $2^2$. Compute $3^2$. Compute $4^2$. Compute $5^2$. Compute $6^2$. And so on.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac {\mathbb Z}{17\mathbb Z}$?  If so, just compute all squares by hand.  $1^2=1,2^2=4,3^2=9,4^2=16,5^2=8,6^2=2,7^2=15,8^2=13$.  No need to go further, as, say, $9=-8$ mod ($17$), so $9^2=8^2$, an so on.

Comment: How and why though...?

Comment: Check out page 90 here http://people.whitman.edu/~gordon/higher_math.pdf

Comment: @JimboJones Because the question is asking you to compute the quadratic residues. But based on your question, I have a feeling you don't know what a quadratic residue is, or what "mod 17" means. Can you write down the definition of these?

Comment: "quadratic residues" means squares.  Same thing.  Of course, if $p$ is a very big number it isn't so easy to just multiply out the entire list.  As to "how", it's easy enough to get the squares, right? so $6^2=36$.  But we are working mod ($17$) so we take remainders on division by $17$.  Thus $36=2*17+2$ so $6^2=36=2$ mod ($17$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quadratic residues are simply found by squaring each of the elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$ (that's just what they are):
\begin{align}
(1)^2&\equiv 1\mod 17\\
(2)^2&\equiv 4\mod 17\\
(3)^2&\equiv 9\mod 17\\
(4)^2&\equiv 16\mod 17\\
(5)^2&\equiv 8\mod 17\\
(6)^2&\equiv 2\mod 17\\
(7)^2&\equiv 15\mod 17\\
(8)^2&\equiv 13\mod 17\\
\end{align}
Since $a^2=(-a)^2$ we only have to check until $8$, because $9\equiv -8\mod 17$, $10\equiv -7\mod 17$, etc.. Thus, the quadratic residues are $\{1,4,9,16,8,2,15,13\}$.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Sorry, I do not fully understand the question you're asking - do you mean how I got $(2)^2\equiv 4\mod 17$? Because, well, $2^2=4$, so this is also true $\mod 17$.